# How do I disable the "Group activity" tab on the organic groups page

Tags: views, 6, organic-groups

I've got organic groups setup in Drupal 6 and have been asked to remove the "Group activity" tab from the groups page (example.com/og). I suspect that this is being driven by one of the views, but I can't seem to find one that is powering it. Is it possible to disable this tab or control its output at least?

This tab appears to have been removed from the Drupal Groups site: http://groups.drupal.org/og

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Tab tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module is a quick and easy way to hide or disable extra tabs.

Comment: This looks really useful; although I suspect there is a proper way of removing this tab without the need for further modules.

Comment: sorry, can't help you with OG on D6. In D7 I don't get a "og" groups page. If the "og" page is a view you can remove the tabs in the view

Comment: OG in D7 didn't seem to provide the same level of support for Views which is part of the reason this project has been in D6. Thanks anyway.